# How can I navigate to next form in Visual studio when I'm using metro framework for c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, metroframework

I have designed two separate forms in my software as Login form and Main form.
Anyone please suggest me a way to navigate between them.I just want to open the Main form when the user enters the correct username and password. Also

```
Form main = new Form();
this.Close();
main.Show();
```

is not working in metro framework.

Thank you!

Comment: have you inherited the MetroForm like this :  public partial class Mainfrm : MetroForm Instead of  public partial class Mainfrm : Form  ??

Answer (score 0):

1) If you know about DATABASE then you have to create a database for username and password put queries in forms and your next form should be opened

2) If not then use if else statements for user name and password and when conditions are true make it open

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it looks like it's asking more about how to swap between winforms effectively, rather then anything to do with databases.